# Cannot add compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2' to The Build Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, bottom-sheet, android-support-design

I'm getting this particular error and my SDK Manager says the Support Directory is already installed.

```
`Error:(11, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:design:27.0.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>`
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please elaborate your issue

Comment: https://medium.com/android-bits/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066
I've been trying to do Bottom Sheet navigation using this tutorial, and that error appeared!

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the dependencies in the **wrong part.**
**Don't add the support libraries in the `buildscript` block and don't add them in the top-level file.**

```
repositories { 
        google() 
        jcenter() 
        maven { url "maven.google.com"; /i added this line } 
     } 
    dependencies { 
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' 

        REMOVE THESE LINES !!!

        compile  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+' //i added this line 
        compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+' // i added this line This is the only place where changes are made
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing 27.0.2 with 27.+ is considered bad practice. Make sure that you are adding the dependency in the correct Gradle file **app/build.gradle** in the dependencies{} block.

Comment: Thanks.. I was compiling against wrong sdk version! Simply changing it fixed the issue! Thanks though!

Comment: Yeah that it often the cause to these problems.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you are adding dependencies in your

> project>app>build.gradle

not in your

> project>build.gradle